# Ax theorem for separably closed fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, model-theory, fields

For the algebraically closed fields a theorem of Ax states that any injective polynomial map from $K^n$ to $K^n$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $K$ an algebraically closed field, is bijective.

Is there an equivalent for the separably closed fields ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In EGA 4 (which was published in 1966 in Publ. IHES, 2 years before Ax 1968 in Annals Math.), Proposition 10.4.11 possibly is a generalization: it says *Let $S$ be a prescheme, $X$ a $S$-prescheme of finite type. Every $S$-endomorphism of $X$ that is radicial is surjective (hence bijective)* [I'm not sure how to translate "radiciel" from French"]. Since I'm not sure of the whole meaning, I'm not sure it answers the question. Note however that the theorem is referred as Ax-Grothendieck theorem and Wikipedia point to this theorem as a reference.

Comment: Thank you. I unfortunately am not familiar with algebraic geometry and I don't see how to relate it to my initial question...
I waS thinking of the model theoretic proof for the algebraically closed fields of fixed characteristic. Since the theory is complete, all we have to do is show the statement for one field. It works with the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ because it is a locally finite field. Can the same proof apply for separably closed field of fixed characteristic since their theory is also complete ?

Comment: Your statement of Ax-Grothendieck (not only Ax) theorem is trivially false for $n<m$.

Comment: Thanks. Of course $n=m$. Sorry I'm editing it.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant "separably closed field of fixed characteristic and fixed imperfection degree"...

Comment: The Frobenius map $F \colon k \to k$ on a separably closed field of characteristic $p > 0$ is an injective polynomial, and is surjective if and only if $k$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn haha, I did't even assume that OP didn't have this trivial example in mind, but hopefully by generalization it is meant that there should be some further assumption on the map, or some further weakening on the surjectivity conclusion.

Comment: The model-theoretic proof does not directly generalize, since the fields which are separably closed but not algebraically closed fields are not locally finite (the separable closure of a finite field is algebraically closed, since finite fields are perfect).